# Code not working with VS Codium, but working with VSCode

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

i have this code

```
from tkinter import *
fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.mainloop()
```

who don't works with VSCodium, but works perfectly fine with VSCode.
I juste added the extension 'Python' from Microsoft on both, nothing more, nothing less.

Someone has an idea why ?
I personally prefer use Codium.

When started from VSCodium i got in the Terminal :

```
andres@andres-linux:~$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    fenetre = tk()
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
```

And with VSCode, no issue, it open a window.

Comment: Please specify what you mean when you say the code „does not work“.

Comment: Post edited with the output in VSCodium

Comment: like Ratnadeep notices, how can the error message say `tk()` but the source code says `Tk()`. The naming for Python2 and Python3 has changed slightly, so use the correct one depending on the book/website you use.

Comment: I know. But, with the same code, and with with the same launch command, which is :
- from VSCode : andres@andres-linux:~$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/andres/Documents/a.py

- from VSCodium : andres@andres-linux:~$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/hello.py

So except the file location and file name, nothing change

Comment: The code in the first block does not match the error in the second block. the first block shows `fenetre = Tk()` (capital T), and the code in the error says `fenetre = tk()` (lowercase t). The first block of code is the correct way to open a tkinter window, the code that generates the error is doing it incorrectly. The first block of code cannot generate the error presented in the second block.

Comment: I assure you that this is the case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import tkinter
fenetre =tkinter.Tk()
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Also after looking carefully at your error line this

```sh
File "/home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
File "/home/andres/Bureau/CoursEPSI/Python/tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    fenetre = tk()
```

I think you need to change `tk` to `Tk`,i.e., `fenetre = tk()` to `fenetre = Tk()`

Comment: Updated answer try that

Comment: Tried, same issue